# Rename MessageConsole in eclipse rcp

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my Eclipse RCP application, I create multiple view instances of the same ViewPart. In the `createPartControl()` method, I have logic to create a `MessageConsole` instance. I add the console instance to the `IConsoleManager` instance . In the `dispose()` method of the view I remove the console. The `MessageConsole` constructor accepts a string argument to name a console. But I don't find any method which will rename a console. How can I achieve this ? I need to rename a console because at times the user can rename the view  and since there is always a `MessageConsole` instance "tied" to a view instance,I want to rename the console as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [`setName`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/console/AbstractConsole.html#setName(java.lang.String)) method on the `AbstractConsole` class?

Comment: I could see that setName method is defined with a protected access modifier. I see 2 possible solutions. Either we use reflection to use the method or extend MessageConsole class and override it there. Any other options possible ?

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the protected attribute.